# How to disable parameter pop-up in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I keep getting this pop-up every time i open a parenthesis and it does not seem to be clickable. How do i disable it?

[image: This is an image showing the pop-up]

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this parameter in setting:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

-> Editor -> General -> Code completion -> Show the parameter info pop-up in "amount" s.

Here's an [image of the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fqsY.png).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

In Mac,

Press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to open settings. Alternatively you can select Preferences from Intellij.

Select Editor -> General -> Code completion. Scroll down to `Parameter Info` section and disable `Show the parameter info popup` checkbox.

In Windows,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to open settings.

Select Editor -> General -> Code completion. Scroll down to `Parameter Info` section and disable `Show the parameter info popup` checkbox.

[image: code autofill changes]